# Holding still multiple datas in one row on datagridview C# Form

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview, string-formatting

It's a weird topic but let me explain it.Im working on a project that receives and sends CANBUS data so fast. Since i have 14 columns of incoming and outgoing data so fast, C# form application couldnt handle this speed(120 rows with 14 columns ~1ms per data). So i decided to reduce the column numbers 14 to 1. That move fixed my performance problem but i had another issues like;

-When incoming data is empty it looks like this "", and a non-empty full data looks like this "00". And my predefined one column seperators are no longer true because of that shift on that row. I created a function that creates placeholder like this "--" if incoming data is empty, but this doesn't work either because of widht of  "FF" and "00" are not same. And my datagridview row starts shaking left to right so fast. It makes table unreadable. Im adding screenshot of both old and new version of that datagridview so you guys have an idea.

[Old version of datagridview 14-column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xrEB.png)
[New version of datagridview 1-columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpi8L.png)

How can i solve this, all ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just by setting DataGridViews DefaultCellStyle property to one fixed(monospaced) font available on Visual Studio. So "11" and "DD" uses same space horizontally as pixels. I used "Consolas" and reset gap between datas. For now its working well. Im adding new screenshot of modified datagridview. Hope it works for you too.

[Modified datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVJW0.png)